# PS4 can not play h264 video

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, hevc, playstation, ps4

## Summary

PS4 Media player can not play h264 mkv, avi or mp4 movies which were converted from HEVC. According the sony's [docs], the media player could be.

source
video: HEVC
audio: AC-3

converted
video: H264
audio: AC-3

Answer (score 0):

## Solutions

### use ffmpeg in 8 bit depth.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -profile:v high -level 4.2 -vf format=yuv420p output.mkv
```

### the resolution must be less than 1080P

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -profile:v high -level 4.2 -vf format=yuv420p,scale=1920:-1 output.mkv  //1080p (1920width × 1080height progressive scan)
```

Comment: Consider adding `-c:a copy` so you don't have to re-encode the audio.